# How to select DJFM season instead of xarray groupby

Tags: python, group-by, python-xarray

I am relatively new to python and programming and have been trying to make some initial plots of precipitation data for the Indian subcontinent specifically for the indian winter monsoon through the period of December, January, February, March.

I have noticed that in groupby('time.season').mean(dim='time') only work for DJF

is there a way to get 4 month (DJFM) seasonal average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the average for a specific set of months over the whole dataset, you can select the months using the time accessor dt and isin, then apply mean. So in your case:

```
da[da.time.dt.month.isin([12,1,2,3])].mean(dim = 'time')
```

If you want the average over a set of 4 months for each year, you can first resample your data to a monthly time step, then calculate the rolling mean over 4 time steps and select the period you want. So in your case:

```
#Resampling
da_ = da.resample(time = '1M').mean()

#Rolling mean
da_ = da_.rolling(time = 4).mean()

#Select March to get the average over DJFM
da_[da_.time.dt.month == 3]
```

Comment: But DJFM means December should be from previous month for eg. if we are taking mean of 2000 it will be 1999 December, 2000 January, 2000 feb and 2000March. and also i am looking for seasonal average means there will be one data in an year which represent the season. But this gives an overall mean

Comment: @gps So you want the yearly value for the season, I edited the answer accordingly.

Note that `groupby('time.season').mean(dim = 'time)` does not give yearly values: you will get the average for all seasons over the whole dataset.